# ArgoCD External helm values issues from gitlab url

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, argocd, gitops

I am currently having trouble deploying my applications with helm on argocd.

I use an Application ressource and I will go to an ApplicationSet next, that I would copy to you in which I must call on values.yml from another repository in my gitlab.

I try to put the link of the repo directly but it does not work.

I haven't found any other solutions to use values ​​files from another gitlab repository.

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance !

My code :

My Application ressource file :

`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: react-docker-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
  project: default
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: argocd
  source:
    repoURL: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/40489526/packages/helm/stable
    targetRevision: 0.8.0
    chart: react-chart
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - https://gitlab.com/maxdev42-gitops-projects/reactdockerapp2/-/blob/master/deployment/valtues.yaml
```

`

My values.yml from an another repository :

`

```
image:
  repository: registry.gitlab.com/maxdev42/react-docker-app
  tag: "appv8"
```

`

I'm trying to use value files from other gitlab repositories to deploy my application on argocd with Helm.

Answer (score 2):

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/multiple_sources/

Helm value file from external source or repository.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is OTS (off-the-shelf).
Here you have an example: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/helm-dependency

Shortly you have to define a new Chart in your repo where you have custom values.yaml referring to a Chart from https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/40489526/packages/helm/stable as dependency.

values.yaml should be changed to:

```
react-chart:
  image:
    repository: registry.gitlab.com/maxdev42/react-docker-app
    tag: "appv7"
```